# Asset Management on Hyperledger Playground

Tags: hyperledger

I installed the playground hyperledger on my local ubuntu VM.

I would like to build an asset management systemt for my company on hyperledger.

Is the playground enough or do I need the fabric. How do I connect more nodes to the playground for redudancy if playground is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Playground is only for development of the chaincode, it runs and stores all data on the browser localStorage, you need the fabric network to deploy it, and is in this network where you define how many peers would exists in the network.